# Data in pivot table not sorting by date correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

Why is the `1/5/2013` data at the top rather than the bottom of my pivot table?  The data itself sorts correctly.

```
Sum of FTE  Column Labels               
Row Labels  162 163 166 168 Grand Total
01/05/2013  1.40    6.13    1.13    1.07    9.73
07/07/2012  2.26    14.36   3.41    3.52    23.55
07/21/2012  2.98    16.78   4.80    4.22    28.78
08/04/2012  2.29    16.08   3.76    4.61    26.74
08/18/2012  3.60    16.07   4.51    3.95    28.14
09/01/2012  3.56    15.70   3.86    4.22    27.34
09/15/2012  2.69    14.70   3.39    4.55    25.34
09/29/2012  2.50    16.57   4.08    4.28    27.43
10/13/2012  3.94    14.77   3.74    3.82    26.27
10/27/2012  3.09    14.10   4.05    4.21    25.45
11/10/2012  2.37    14.75   4.75    4.58    26.45
11/24/2012  1.79    11.92   2.95    3.41    20.07
12/08/2012  3.09    15.40   3.37    3.69    25.55
12/22/2012  3.10    13.41   2.70    2.87    22.08
Grand Total 38.66   200.75  50.49   53.00   342.90
```

Comment: If those date-cells are not in Date format, the underlying value will be text- and such, sorted left-right.  Only if in the Date format will it have underlying time values that can be sorted chronologically.

Answer (score 2):

Are the dates really dates? Or text that looks like dates? You can find out when you go to the data source, select one of the date cells and apply a different date format.

You may need to convert the text that looks like dates to real dates, then refresh the pivot table.